# Order BY one table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables   (SQL Fiddle available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bcb5b)):

People

```
ID          Company_ID        Name
1            1                Jones
2            2                Smith
3            3                Kim
4            2                Takahashi
5            3                Patel
6            1                Muler
```

Companies

```
ID           Name
1            QQQ
2            AAA
3            MMM
```

I wish to order a selection of People by the Name of the Company they work for.

SELECT * FROM People WHERE (Some where clause) ORDER BY   **HELP!**

Comment: You don't want the *name* of the company in the output?  You only want the  ordering by the name?

Comment: That is correct.  Only the output order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `join` both tables:

```
SELECT   p.* 
FROM     People p
JOIN     Companies c ON c.ID = p.CompaniyID
WHERE    --(Some where clause) 
ORDER BY c.Name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM People INNER JOIN Companies ON Company_ID = Companies.ID ORDER BY Companies.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the people table with the companies table to do that. You can do that by a cartesian product, which can be done by an explicit join clause or just a comma between each table in the from. A condition is also required to tell which field from the first table needs to correspond with the field of the second table, otherwise each row in table one is linked with each row of table two, which is not what you want in this case.

So this is what it would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_ONE,
       TABLE_TWO
WHERE
       FOREIGN_KEY_IN_TABLE_ONE = PRIMARY_KEY_IN_TABLE_TWO
ORDER BY
       COLUMN_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_SORT_ON
```

Other syntax with join clauses would go like this

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_ONE INNER JOIN TABLE_TWO ON FOREIGN_KEY_TABLE_ONE = PRIMARY_KEY_TABLE_TWO
ORDER BY
       COLUMN_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_SORT_ON
```

Try to read up on the join methods. INNER JOIN is not the only possibility.